# Python while loop does not terminate after exceeding range (0, 10), but for loops do. Why is that?

Tags: python, loops

If I use a while loop for the below code it never moves on to printing my list "Comm", but if I only change while to for it works as intended - printing all common integers in on a single line in shell.

```
a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]
b = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]

x = 0

Comm = [] #common int in both lists

while x in range(0,len(a)):
    if a[x] in b:
        Comm.append(a[x])
        x += 1
print(Comm)
```

Comment: did you intend to put the ```x += 1``` in the if condition?

Comment: Will x increase in a while loop without that?

Comment: x will not increase.  I think you meant to use a for loop, i.e. ```for x in range(len(a)):``` and then remove ```x += 1```

Comment: This is a terrible way to write this and leads to the kind or error you are seeing. Just use `for n in a`  and forget about all the indexing. Then you can just use `if n in b` and `append(n)`. Better yet, use a set intersection and you can loose the loop altogether with something like `Comm = list(set(a).intersection(b))`

Comment: I see. So a for loop doesn't need the `x += 1`either?  Must be an old habit from visual basic.

Comment: Right, you can often get away without dealing with indices in Python, which makes a lot of things easier to reason about and a lot of errors easier to avoid.

Comment: a set intersection is so simple! I gotta wonder why this textbook doesn't mention them at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `for` loop instead of `while`.

If `x` goes from 0 to 6, then `a[6] = 13`. `a[6]` is in `b`, so `x` becomes 7 and `a[7] = 21`.

`a[7]` is not in `b`, so `x` doesn't increase. It means that `x` stops at 7 and doesn't break out of the `while` loop.